# ATL Interface Pointers: replace get_ and put_

Tags: com, properties, atl, smart-pointers

I did ATL programming many years ago and now going down that path again. I remember last time, there was a way for the compiler to optimize put_ and get_ (that is properties) automatically. I really cannot find out how I did it last time.

Currently I am doing this:

```
// assume p is a pointer to an interface
CComBSTR name;
p->get_Name(&name);
```

This code is really bugging me, and I am sure there is a better way:

```
// can we do this?
CComBSTR name(p->get_Name());
// or maybe this
CComBSTR name(p->Name);
```

I could not figure out how to do this using CComPtr and _com_ptr_t. Also note that p is a pointer to an interface in the same library. So I am not using #import or anything.

Comment: If you used `#import`, it would have created these property style accessors for you.

Comment: @RomanR. That is correct. But I am dealing with an interface within the same library. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Within the same library you don't have these accessors handy, you have `_i.h` file instead with raw pointers. You could of course create a helper class, but this defeats the purpose of obtaining them automatically. I thought you might want to re-`#import` your type library into a side namespace and having this code on hands access your private interface pointers with these auto-generated classes. I don't think I would ever do it myself, but still looks doable and possibly helpful.

Comment: @RomanR. I got it to work if I import the library's own tlb (in Debug and Release folder). Not sure if there is a neater way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

CComBSTR name(p->Name); is the right thing